# Outputting a bool to the Console

Tags: c#

This is an easy question I think :-)

Have a look at this program:

```
string v1 = "Hallo";
string v2 = "Hallo";

Console.WriteLine("Output" + v1 == v2);
```

This just outputs the following:

> False

But if I write:

```
Console.WriteLine("Output" + true);
```

It outputs:

> OutputTrue

I would think that "v1 == v2" evualuates to "true" and is therefore the same.
But I am obviously wrong.

Can anyone explain this behaviour to me? I expected to get the same result (OutputTrue) in both cases. What is happening in the first case?

Comment: Put a parenthesis on the v1+v2 on the first statement, what happening is that the clr understand that you concatenating "output" + v1, and the doing the equal statement, doing "output" + (v1 + v2) should print the correct output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It firsts adds `v1` to `"Output"` so you'll get the following statement:

`Console.WriteLine("OutputHallo" == v2);`

To fix this you can add parenthisis:

`Console.WriteLine("Output" + (v1 == v2));`

Comment: Haha! I knew there is an easy explanation for this. So concatentation in C# is higher than == Nice to know!

Comment: @DavidElsner Can you mark the answer as solved please?

Comment: @DavidElsner it's a good practice to always use parenthesis, as it makes the operators order (and programmer intention)  clear for everybody reading the code. It also avoids mistakes like this one.

Answer (score 0):

Reference types are checked whether same references point to the same object in memory, not the value itself.

Although string is a reference type, the equality operators (== and !=) are defined to compare the values of string objects, not references. This behavior is overridden for strings in c#.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/reference-types

Comment: That's not what's happening in C#:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/l3nfwV

Comment: Yeah - string is a reference type but the == operator is overloaded like it was a value type. Can be confusing!

Comment: Yes, sorry , updated the answer. ))